# does the base of a seek operation affect how fast it runs, or is it just how some standard offset is computed?

Tags: python, file-io, seek

Eg, in python, is this:

```
with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
  f.seek(0, 2)  # seek to EOF
  file_size = f.tell()

  f.seek(file_size - 10)
  print f.read(10)

  f.seek(file_size - 20)
  print f.read(10)

  f.seek(file_size - 30)
  print f.read(10)
  ...
```

any less efficient than this:

```
with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
  f.seek(-10, 2)
  print f.read(10)

  f.seek(-20, 1)
  print f.read(10)

  f.seek(-20, 1)
  print f.read(10)
  ...
```

Comment: It's the same. And use `with` when working with files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The read position in a file is a simple index maintained by the OS kernel; there is no physical head movements involved.

The C code subtracting 10 from the current position or you calculating the new position in python will make very little difference.

Comment: This is somewhat inaccurate, the position is managed by the kernel, not the userspace C libraries. Calling `f.tell` or `f.seek` results in an `lseek` syscall.

Comment: @phihag: that doesn't matter much to the performance story, but I corrected the statement.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't matter for performance? I'd assume the syscall itself is very slow compared to just looking up a value in userspace (the performance of the whole application, at least as presented here, is indeed most likely completely independent of any python code and dwarfed by the load time of the python interpreter). And having a closer look, I must retract my earlier comment - at least my libc caches the current index in userspace.

Comment: I said from the perspective of Python; either the C library handles it all or the kernel does. The OP seems to be under the impression that some sort of physical head move is taking place, where a small relative seek is 'cheaper' or not than an absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the programs are not identical since `read` moves the cursor position! So you want to call `f.seek(-20, 1)` unless you want to read the same 10 bytes over and over.

Also, the additional call to `ftell` may make the first one (imperceptibly) slower. Another difference between your programs is that they behave slightly differently if the file is being written to while you're reading it.

Also note that you can directly seek from EOF, like this:

```
with open('myfile', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(-10, 2) # Seek from EOF
    print(f.read(10))

    f.seek(-20, 1)
    print(f.read(10))

    f.seek(-20, 1)
    print(f.read(10))
```